# hosting mutiple sites on IIS6 windows server 2003

Tags: iis-6, hosting, dns, sites

Hi
I have 2 domains , egmahdi.com and 4xstats.com 
The first domain which I bought was egMahdi.com , I set the nameservers to ns1.egmahdi.com and ns2.egmahdi.com , 
after that I used the DNS server in my VPS and IIS for hosting the site and there were no problem , 
I just registered the second domain '4xsttas.com' and made the same steps I had done for egmahdi.com (in DNS server and IIs )
but now the problem is that I can not access the new website and my browser always says 'website not found' , But I can access the website when typing it's address in my VPS' Browser , 
I would really appreciate it if some one help me solve the problem .
really thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4xsttas.com does not resolve for me. If you ping it the domain name, what happens?

Comment: Hi,tnx  , the problem was resolved after one day , I think there is  something like website names cache on my ISP , which is updated every one day , by the way the domain is 4xstats.com which is successfully pinged right now , really tnx for your attention to my question ,